# Custom criteria to determine if file is modified

Tags: git

I'm writing documents with latex, and my compiler (latexmk and pdflatex) always replaces the old pdf file. Git always views this file as modified, even when the pdf is identical, presumably because some metadata is being modified.

There are various utilities (imagemagick's compare) that can compare only the content of pdfs. Is there any way to have git only register a file as modified only when an external command reports it as such?

Comment: Why are you even tracking the PDF? It's a generated file. If you simply "gitignored" it and only tracked the source files (`.tex`, `.bib`,  etc.), you wouldn't run into such issues.

Comment: Chek this out:  https://gist.github.com/thbar/4943276  it sounds like to do what you want would require an OS script based on a diff.

Comment: I would prefer to have the pdf file in the repository, so I have a canonical version to compare with other compilations. There are a few latex compilers and environments, and I hope but do not know that they will provide consistent formatting.

My current method is generating an ignored staging pdf, which I then use  make to compare and possibly copy. But this something of a kludge.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that's not possible.

But if you can easily generate the PDF files from your latex inputs, just don't put them into your repository (cf. [gitignore](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/docs/gitignore)).